# Enviar valor entre ventanas en Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Tengo una ScreenView que contiene una serie de botones generados automáticamente de una lista. Quiero que al pulsar un botón determinado se cambie la ventana actual por otra Screen, y que en esta se muestre el número del boton que le envio. El objetivo de esta ventana va a ser realmente que tras haber pulsado un botón quede regristrado el id pulsado para posteriormente emplear este valor para buscar datos pero con saber pasar el número me valdría. Lo que tengo hasta ahora es lo siguiente:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock


Builder.load_string('''
<Manager>:
    VentanaBotones:
    VentanaMostrarNumero:


<VentanaBotones>:
    id: grupo
    name: 'botones'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ScrollView:
            id: scroll
            ContenedorBotones:

<ContenedorBotones>:
    id: contenedor
    cols: 1
    size_hint_y: None
    spacing:5
    height: self.minimum_height

<Botones>:
    id_boton: ''
    id: root.id_boton
    padding: 100, 0
    text: root.id_boton
    size_hint_y :None
    height: 70
    on_press:
        botones.numero_seleccionado = root.id_boton
        botones.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        botones.manager.current = 'mostrar' 

<VentanaMostrarNumero>:
    name: 'mostrar'
    Label:
        text: root.numero_seleccionado

''')

numero_seleccionado = StringProperty()

class VentanaMostrarNumero(Screen):
    numero_seleccionado = StringProperty(str(numero_seleccionado))
    pass

class VentanaBotones(Screen):
    pass

class ContenedorBotones(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ContenedorBotones, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.generarBotones)

    def generarBotones(self,*args):
        lista = [i for i in range (25)]
        for i in lista:
            b = Botones()
            b.id_boton = str(i)
            self.add_widget(b)


class Botones(Button):
    id_boton = StringProperty(None)

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class PrincipalApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PrincipalApp().run()
```

He probado a hacerle referencia mediante el id y no funciona, mediante root en el botón hago referencia al elemento boton. No sé como podría mandar este valor. Mi idea principal ha sido crear una variable global que sea la tome el valor y luego mostarla en la otra clase. No he podido encontrar mucha información sobre manejar datos. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta siempre que en kv languaje, `root` dentro de una regla siempre hace referencia al objeto cuya nombre está entre `<>`. Las ids tampoco son accesibles desde otra regla.

Ésto no es generalmente ningún problema porque se suele instanciar en el propio kv languaje, por lo que estas limitaciones desaparecen. El problema es que tus botones en el .kv son solo una mera regla que no se conectan con el resto y se instancia en Python, lo que nos limita a la hora de conectarlos via ids por ejemplo, por lo que solo nos queda el atributo `parent` y `app` para referenciar cosas que esté por encima en la jerarquía.

Yo, a la hora de compartir variables entre pantallas, lo que hago es crear una  property en el `ScreenManager` que las contiene, luego desde cualquier ventana puedes acceder a ellas mediante `self.manager.property_name` de forma simple.

En tu caso, hay un problema más, la callback asociada al evento `on_press`  de cada botón tiene que terminar referenciando al `ScreenManager`, lo que requiere usar `self.parent.parent.parent.manager`..., otra opción mucho más simple es hacer que la propia app (`PrincipalApp`) mantenga la instancia del manager asociada a una property, con ésto, desde cualquier parte podemos acceder a él mediante `app.screen_manager`.

En general la instancia de `App` es un buen lugar para almacenar variables globales de la aplicación, dado que siempre podrá ser referenciada desde dónde sea.

---

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock


Builder.load_string('''
<Manager>:
    numero_seleccionado: ""
    VentanaBotones
    VentanaMostrarNumero

<VentanaMostrarNumero>:
    name: 'mostrar'
    Label:
        text: root.manager.numero_seleccionado

<VentanaBotones>:
    id: grupo
    name: 'botones'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ScrollView:
            id: scroll
            ContenedorBotones:

<ContenedorBotones>:
    id: contenedor
    cols: 1
    size_hint_y: None
    spacing:5
    height: self.minimum_height

<Boton>:
    manager: None
    id_boton: ''
    padding: 100, 0
    text: self.id_boton
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 70
    on_press:
        app.screen_manager.numero_seleccionado = self.id_boton
        app.screen_manager.transition.direction = "right"
        app.screen_manager.current = 'mostrar'
 ''')


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    numero_seleccionado = StringProperty()


class VentanaMostrarNumero(Screen):
    pass


class VentanaBotones(Screen):
    pass


class ContenedorBotones(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.generar_botones)

    def generar_botones(self, *args):
        for i in range(25):
            b = Boton()
            b.id_boton = str(i)
            self.add_widget(b)


class Boton(Button):
    id_boton = StringProperty(None)


class PrincipalApp(App):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()

    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = Manager()
        return self.screen_manager


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PrincipalApp().run()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, nunca había usado "app" para llamar a una función así.

Comment: De nada, por cierto, si necesitas acceder a la instancia de app desde Python se puede hacer con `app = App.get_running_app()`, en mi ejemplo, desde cualquier parte del código puedes acceder al manager con `App.get_running_app().screen_manager`, igual que hace `app.screen_manager` en el .kv. Saludos